# MS Word 2010 margin information messagebox not showing always on top

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm attaching word files to a .Net application. The file I'm attaching has some marginal issues. When attaching this file MS word pop ups a message saying that "The margin of section 1 are set outside the printable area". But in my PC this pop up is not appearing as always on top where as some other machines showing this pop up as always on top. Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to File -> Options -> Compatibility Options -> Expand Layout Options and make sure *Use Printer Metrics to lay out Document* is unchecked. Having this option enabled can cause printing problems when you transport your document to different machines.

Additionally I believe I caught from your description you are using Word automation and this popup is interfering with the commands sent to Word from your application? If this is the case, I highly suggest using a third party library which can faithfully convert and print Word documents without using Microsoft Word.